# How do I create a procedure that will return a single message in a chat

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

[image: This is my chat table]

[image: and This is my procedure "InsertChat" which send the first message in a chat]

I want to create a new procedure that will receive a message from [dbo].[Chats] table (where its's messages were insert through InsertChat procedure by a user - look at the picture) and the receiver will answer that message.
every message has its own ID int identity (1,1).

---

I tried -

```
create proc ReceiveChat
    @Sender int, 
    @Receiver int, 
    @ChatID int,
    @SenderMessage nvarchar(80)
as
Begin 
  select [dbo].[Chats].*
  From [dbo].[Chats] 
  where  ([Sender] = @Sender) and ([Receiver] = @Receiver)  and ([Chat_ID]= @ChatID)
     insert into [dbo].[Chats] (Chat)
     values ( @SenderMessage)
  END
```

---

Thanks

Comment: If your time is short, asking people to do your work (for free) on a Q&A website is the wrong choice

Comment: This doesn't add any new information. Your data structure is odd and also your procedures. It is not really clear what you are trying to do. And also in that procedure why would you want to select by using not only the primary key but other (sender, receiver) fields as well? What would you do with the select result?

Comment: You've **just asked** this very same question only 6 hours ago - please **DO NOT** post the same question over and over and over again . If you didn't get any responses, maybe your question isn't clear enough or you're not showing relevant pieces of the question - please update your **existing** question with more details - don't just repost again and again ....

Comment: @Lmu92  its a work in a class not a JOB, you scaredy little one,   think I want money ? who send here question just for his own funnnnnnnnnnn? ohh o.k i get we all just waste are time in the world. I'm a student by the whey. didnt understand how to create message table if every chat message has unique id.

Answer (score 2):

Your table structure is missing a grouping column to separate different chats. This is important since the person assigned "sender" or "receiver" will chang in a chat depending on who's sending the message to whom.

So, from my point of view there needs to be rethinking of the process and a different data model for it. For instance: a chat table (what people belong to a specific chat) and a separate message table that relates back to the chat table.

Your comment "my time is short I have to deliver it" scares me! Are you actually getting paid by using the answers we provide? If so, then you might call a consultant...

Comment: its a work in a class not a JOB, you scaredy one. think I want money ? who send here question just for funnnnnnnnnnn? ohh o.k i get we all just waste are time our world. I'm a student by the whey. And I didnt understand how to create message table if every chat message has unique id.

Comment: If it's homework for a student then there are a few ways to tackle it: Show us the task, what you've and where you get stuck. Right now we only have a small portion of the picture. Tell us what we need to know and we might be able to give you a hint for the right direction. Not the exact solution though, since most of us around here had to earn their degree by themselves...